# How can I change height of the view which is present in StackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a custom UIView using for Custom UITabBar whose height is fixed 50 and I am adding a stackview for each button but I need middle button height should be more.

```
let view: UIView = views[3]
view.heightAnchor.equalToConstant(100.0).isActive = true

let stackView: UIStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [views])
     stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     stackView.axis = .horizontal
     stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
     addSubview(stackView)
     stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
     stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
     stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
     stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

How can I change the height of a particular view inside the stackView?

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your problem but you can change anyviews height  using constraints as you have already done.
It is same when the view is subview of a stackview. Stackview updates it's size to satisfy its constraint.
You have to have a reference to height constraint of the view inside stackview.
Then you can change it whenever need to.
Also it would be nice to set stackviews `alignment` property to have desired look.

```
let heightConstraint = view.heightAnchor.equalToConstant(100.0)
heightConstraint.isActive = true
.
.
.
heightConstraint.constant = 150
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the `Alignment` property of the stack view...

Assuming 5 views, each with a height constraint of 60, and you want the 4th view (`views[3]`) to have a height of 100.

StackView Alignment `Top`:

[image]

StackView Alignment `Center`:

[image]

StackView Alignment `Bottom`:

[image]